# C# OdbcDataReader.GetBoolean InvalidCastException In IF-Statement

Tags: c#, postgresql, odbc

Please forgive my broken English first.

Well,antiduh's method of debug helps me to know what happen on my code,thanks everyone who join discuss.

---

When I use OdbcDataReader.GetBoolean single,it's OK and no problem,just like below:

```
OdbcDataReader reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
checkBox1.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(0);
```

no problem wiil occur.

BUT!!

I need to ascertain the column is Null or not,so I use if-statement as below:

```
OdbcDataReader reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == false)
    checkBox1.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(0);
```

It will occur InvalidCastException error on reader.GetBoolean(0)

I have no idea about this problem,does somebody can help me? please~

---

According to antiduh's valuable comment,
I found that if reader.GetValue(0) isn't in if-statement as below:

```
OdbcDataReader reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
var foo = reader.GetValue(0);
```

It wiil return True or False.

But if reader.GetValue(0) is in interior of if-statement as below:

```
OdbcDataReader reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == false)
{
    var foo = reader.GetValue(0);
}
```

It will return 1 or 0.

So if I use GetBoolean to transform 1 or 0 to bool data type,will occur InvalidCastException.

Now I know what happen on my code,but still don't know what the difference between two codes.

---

Thanks antiduh's valuable comment again,

I try this code that antiduh provide below:

```
OdbcDataReader reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == false)
{
    try
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(0);
    }
    catch ( InvalidCastException e ) {
        object doubleCheck = reader.GetValue(0);
        Console.WriteLine( "Tried to cast this type: " + doubleCheck.GetType() );
    }
}
```

It wiil return: Tried to cast this type:System.String

And doubleCheck.ToString() is 1 or 0.

Comment: Does your command return more than 1 row?  Are you sure that every value in the column can be converted to a Boolean?  Instead of nulls does the column have 0-length (empty) strings?

Comment: Just 1 row,and the column in Database actually Bool type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its likely that the value in that row and column is not actually a bool. Add some temporary debugging code to catch the exception and call GetValue instead, and look to see what you're actually getting back.

```
OdbcDataReader reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == false)
{
    try {
        checkBox1.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(0);
    }
    catch ( InvalidCastException e ) {
        object doubleCheck = reader.GetValue(0);

        Console.WriteLine( "Tried to cast this type: " + doubleCheck.GetType() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well,I found that if reader.GetValue(0) isn't in if-statement,it wiil return True or False.

But if reader.GetValue(0) is in interior of if-statement,it will return 1 or 0.

So I think maybe if-statement wiil change format ?

Comment: Check out the code I just added. It'll dump the type of the actual value there, which will tell you why GetBoolean is failing to cast. One idea, it may be possible that this is some bug between the Odbc driver and postgres. Perhaps use a different mechanism to interface to your postgres database, like a postgres-native library.

Comment: Excuse me first,12 hours ago my location is almost midnight. I try your code you added,and return Tried to cast this type: System.String.

Comment: Try printing doubleCheck, see what the value actually is. If it's "1" or "0", it seems like the Odbc driver is modifying the underlying type in route between the database server and your app. You may have to do the casting and parsing by hand if you can't make it keep it as a Boolean type.

Comment: Yes,it's 1 or 0. Thank you again.